# Can't install Ubuntu 22.04LTS in my laptop

Tags: boot, system-installation, pulseaudio, 22.04, pxe

I wanted to install ubuntu on my laptop. Everythings goes fine(except there's an error "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is not owned by us (uid 0), but by uid 999!(This could eg happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that.").

After completing the installation it shows that "ububtu has installed. You have to restart".after i restart my laptop it shows to remove install medium and then enter. When i do that it blinks two time and then shows some error.

PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable PXE-MOF: Exiting Intel Boot Agent.

Then it shows that please install some operating system in your hard drive. I tried 2-3 times but everytime it ends up this way. My previous system is gone as i want to erase everything and install ubuntu. What to do now

[Boot order in UFEI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69cQ1.jpg)

[Boot order in Legacy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQEJi.jpg)

Comment: You need to open UEFI (or BIOS if older than circa 2012) and check your boot order. The PXE error means it's trying to boot from the network and failing.

Comment: I updated the post with my laptop's boot order pictures. I tried both UEFI and Legacy boot. In Legacy the problem is same as i discussed in my post. Then i tried in UEFI and everytime i turn on the laptop the screen shows reset system and again restart my laptop and continue in a loop

Comment: now i found that i can boot manually from boot option. When i boot from notebook hard drive the problem appears. But there's an another option in boot menu "boot from EFI file". From here i can boot the system.